# Html dynamic button onclick dropdown onchange not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
htmlButton = '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 padding5px"><button id =' + result[i].DivisionID + ' class= "btn btn-primary elmer_button" type="button" Name=' + result[i].DivisionName + ' onclick="RedirectLogIn(' + result[i].DivisionID + ')">' + result[i].DivisionName + '</button></div>'

var RedirectLogIn = function (item) {
    alert(item);
};
```

Comment: Do you add the `htmlButton` string to the DOM at any point?

Comment: yes Rory,  $("#btnDivisions").append(htmlButton);

Comment: Given what little code you've shown your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/q7mzhq26/. Can you give us a more complete example, or details of any errors you have in the console

Comment: It is working fine for mozila but in IE11 not working properly. Even there is no error shown in console. Just the event isn't firing.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know what is in your array and when/how/where you add "htmlButton" to the DOM I can only assume

```
result[i].DivisionID
```

doesn't include double quotation marks.
So when you try to use it to set a name and assign it as an element to RedirectLogIn it just puts the content of the element without the necessary marks.

Try something like this

```
htmlButton = '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 padding5px">';
htmlButton += '<button id="' + result[i].DivisionID + '" '; 
htmlButton += 'class= "btn btn-primary elmer_button" type="button" name="'; 
htmlButton += result[i].DivisionName; 
htmlButton += '" onclick="RedirectLogIn("'; 
htmlButton += result[i].DivisionID;
htmlButton += '")">';
htmlButton += result[i].DivisionName + '</button></div>';
```

As you can see I've added double quotation marks right before and after your single ones when you insert something from the array

P.S.: Please try ordering your code a bit better next time.

Comment: Division Id is like 1,2,3,4. And I bind that html as $("#btnDivisions").append(htmlButton); It is working fine in mozila but problem is for IE.

Comment: how do you get 'i'? Might be that the event is never added because 'i' isn't anything.